# Unable to click button

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

im very new to Javascript and was wondering if you could help, im using waitForKeyElements in my script however i cannot get it to click the button on the site in the script.

```
/*- This is the html of the button i'd like to click when it appears

<div id="battleInfo">
<center>You are out of autos 
<a href="#" onclick="phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto();">Restart</a>
</center>
</div>

*/


// ==UserScript==
// @name         Autoscript
// @version      0.1
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require      http://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @include      http://tpt-rpg.com/auto_battle.php
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function clickattack (jNode) {
var clickEvent = document.createEvent
('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, ture);
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

waitForKeyElements (
"button[onclick*='phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto()']"",
clickattack);
```

Comment: do you want the button to be pressed as soon as the page is finished loading and then automatically run the function? - also I see at the second last line, do you need to have two quotes? i think one should be removed to close the starting one at the beginning of the line

Comment: i want it to click the button when it appears after the auto battles run out

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching an event to a button, but it's actually defined as being attached to an anchor in the html. So you could try

```
"a[onclick*='phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto()']"",
```

instead of

```
"button[onclick*='phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto()']"",
```

but why not give your anchor an id so you could just use the id to find it? Like so:

```
<a id="restartAnchor" href="#" onclick="phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto();">Restart</a>
```

and

```
"#restartAnchor[onclick*='phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto()']"",
```

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with waitForKeyElement, but it appears to be finding things using a css selector.

Comment: to assign an anchor i would have to modify the element before clicking so it can identify it?

Comment: i have tried the above variations and it does not click the button

Comment: sorry, the last line of code there should be waitForKeyElements ("#restartAnchor", clickattack);

Comment: but on the site it looks to me there is no anchor id set, as my previous reply would i have to modify it to add an id to it for it to work and if so how should i do it?

Comment: How you choose to add an id is arbitrary. This should work: waitForKeyElements("a[onclick*='phoenixtales.battle.restartBattleAuto()']", clickattack), but I suggest you open your browser's developer interface and see if the css/jquery path identifying your anchor actually works. Include jquery, put a breakpoint in the java script and add a watch